# Double for loop doesn't work

Tags: statistics, graphing-functions, data-analysis

I have 100000 iid normal variables X1, . . . , X100000 from N(0,1) and for i ∈ {2, . . . , 100000} and want to plot the graph of the function \

$$ R_i = \frac{\max{X_j}}{\sqrt{2 \log i}} $$

where  j=1,...,i. And Repeat the above experiment 10 times and plot the respective trajectories of Ri
on the same graph. I tried this code

```
sample<- rnorm(100000,mean=0,sd=1)
i=2:100000
r=0
for (i in 2:100000){
  for (j in 1:i){
    r[i]=(max(sample[j]))/(sqrt(2*log(i)))
  }
}
plot(r)
```

But the results are not logical. I think the for loop doesn't work properly in max(X_j) but I don't know where. Also how to repeat it 10 times, could you please help? Thank you!

Comment: A first comment: you define $i$ before the first for loop (line 2). I don't know how R reacts to this, but this does not seem like a good idea.

Comment: Also, and this is probably your problem, you should not take sample[j] but rather sample from $1$ up to $j$ for your max. Take sample[1:j] instead.

Comment: Since you're looking for a maximum value, I would do it so that I define a new variable, and every time a new value is pulled from the sample, then it's compared to the old maximum value. So either an if-statement or just a max() of two items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of a programming question as it is not quite about the [law of the iterated logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_iterated_logarithm).

R has a `cummax` function so you could do something like

```
set.seed(2020)
r <- function(samplesize){
  s <- rnorm(samplesize, mean=0, sd=1)
  cummax(s) / sqrt(2*log(1:samplesize))
  }
simulations <- replicate(10, r(10^5))
matplot(simulations, type="l")
```

to get something like

[image]